# What does the Ito integral provide?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

In the context of derivatives pricing, I have read about calculating the Ito integral to get the expectation of a random variable, but am having trouble developing an intuitive sense of its significance. My impression has been that the information derived is the same as what I could get from plain descriptive statistics using the mean and variance. I assume this is wrong, so what is the additional information that the Ito integral gives you in reference to the expectation?

Comment: I feel like you may have some more foundational misunderstandings...the Ito integral is baked into the way you formulate a stochastic process model in the first place. The basic intuition is that you have some instantaneous volatility $\sigma_t$ and in a short time interval $[t,t+dt]$ the stochastic contribution to the evolution of some process $X_t$ is $\sigma_t$ times a N(0,$dt$) random variable, with the N(0,$dt$) variables being independent of each other. This is not formally correct but it captures the main idea.

Comment: (Cont.) Maybe you're asking about the utility of explicit calculations like $\int_0^t W_s dW_s = \frac{W_t^2-t}{2}$?